# Run Method From Stacked Activity When Back Button Is Pressed From Another Activity

Tags: android

I have `Activity A` that has`Method A` and `Button A` so whenever I press Button A it calls an intent to start `Activity B` without finishing Activity A (it is stacked under Activity B). When I press the `BackButton` on Activity B I return back to Activity A (so far so good) however at this point I woiuld like Method A to then run when Activity A is revealed after back button is pressed from Activity B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return to the `ActivityA`, the method `onResume` of `ActivityA` will be called. So you can do the following:

1. Create a boolean inside the `ActivityA` named `didLoadActivity = false`
2. Inside the `onResume` of `ActivityA` add the following:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if(didLoadActivity) {
           methodA(); // here you call the Method A
       } else {
           didLoadActivity = true;
       }
   }
   ```